# Extracting names from JSON file

Tags: python, json

Im trying to get only the names of playlist from a json file that I have but I cannot make it

```
{'playlists': [{'description': '',
                'lastModifiedDate': '2018-11-20',
                'name': 'Piano',
                'numberOfFollowers': 0,
                'tracks': [{'artistName': 'Kenzie Smith Piano',
                            'trackName': "You've Got a Friend in Me (From "
                                         '"Toy Story")'},
                           {'artistName': 'Kenzie Smith Piano',
                            'trackName': 'A Whole New World (From "Aladdin")'},
                           {'artistName': 'Kenzie Smith Piano',
                            'trackName': 'Can You Feel the Love Tonight? (From '
                                         '"The Lion King")'},
                           {'artistName': 'Kenzie Smith Piano',
                            'trackName': "He's a Pirate / The Black Pearl "
                                         '(From "Pirates of the Caribbean")'},
                           {'artistName': 'Kenzie Smith Piano',
                            'trackName': "You'll be in My Heart (From "
                                         '"Tarzan") [Soft Version]'},

import json
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('C:/Users/alvar/Desktop/Alvaro/Nueva carpeta/Playlist.json', encoding="utf8").read()

playlist = json.loads(json_data)
pprint(playlist)
```

Here is where is not working:

```
for names in playlist_list:
    print(names['name'])
    print '\n'
```

What I want is to extract only the names of the playlists.

Comment: So you expect us to divine the error in your code? What error are you getting - edit the full error message into your question.

Comment: What is `playlist_list`?

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to you not accessing the dictionary key `'playlists'`

```
for plst in playlist['playlists']:
    print(plst['name'])

# Piano
```

Comment: The question asked for the name of the playlist, not for the name of the tracks.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate on the wrong object.

Do not forget that `json.loads(json_data)` return the object as it is stored. In your case, it's a dict with only one element : `'playlist'`. You have to access this element with `loaded_json['playlist']` then iterate over the list of playlist.

Here, `loaded_json` is of type `Dict[List[Dict]]`. Be careful with JSON and nested data structures.

Try :

```
loaded_json= json.loads(json_data)       #type: Dict[List[dict]]
for playlist in loaded_json['playlist']: #type: dict
    print('{}\n'.format(playlist['name']))
```

By doing this, you will get all the playlist's name.

Documentation: [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html)